# How can I delete all the resources allocated by an activity when I click on the back button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-profiler

I have two activities MainActivity and SecondActivity. The MainActivity has a button, when I click on it I go to the SecondActivity, in this activity I do some math calculations (the code required to do this calculation is very large with 100 of classes) in a separate thread, when the calculation is done , I display the result in a Textview. when the user clicks the back button it goes back to MainActivity, till this moment everything is fine but when i profiled the code in android studio i found that many classes of the calculate function are kept , for example static variables, enumerations, etc. so to solve this problem I am trying to remove some static variables, through this approach I reduce the amount of code withheld but I can't go any further. Is there any solution to this problem, so when I click the back button, all the resources allocated by the SecondActivity (calculate function) should be deleted.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

            Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            });
        }
    }

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        private TextView mTextView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

            mTextView = findViewById(R.id.textview);

            Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
                String result = calculate();
                displayResult(result);
            });
            thread.start();
        }

        String calculate(){
            //pure java code
            //Very complex math operation with 100 of classes
            return "result";
        }

        public void displayResult(String result){
            mHandler.post(() -> {
                mTextView.setText(result);
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it but i think this will work.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
        startActivity(intent);
        SecondActivity.this.finish(); // if the activity running has it's own context
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work, it recreates the main activity but this activity still in the back stack, I also get a leak warning.